# how to hook beforeRouteEnter in NuxtJs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to get the previous route for my nuxtjs app, so for i used `beforeRouteEnter`, but `beforeRouteEnter` is not firing.

***i tried to add key in nuxt-link :*** *and still not working..*

```
<nuxt-link :key="$route.path" :to="'/services/'+service.id">
```

**so here is my code:**

```
  created: function(){
    console.log("created");
  },

  mounted: function(){
    console.log("mounted");
  },

  mounted: function(){
    console.log("mounted");
  },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {

    console.log("before route called");

    next(vm => {
      console.log("prev rout is: "+vm.prevRoute);
    })

  }
```

**i expected :**

```
before route called
prev rout is: /services
created
mounted
```

**but i only get :**

```
created
mounted
```

Is there anything that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you only looking in the browser console? beforeRouteEnter is probably logging in the terminal.

Comment: @Andrew1325
 yeah. i checked in both console and terminal. still not printing

Comment: This must only apply to previous versions, cos it worked just fine for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying your code in my current project based on nuxt ˆ2.0.0, I report to you my dev tools console, after navigation from / route to /_slug route.

```
_slug.js:200 before route called
_slug.js:192 created
_slug.js:198 mounted
_slug.js:205 prev rout is: undefined
```

When I refresh the page _slug is the same.

If you want the previous route why don't simply do:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
   console.log("before route called");
   const previousRoute = from.path || from.fullPath
   console.log(`Previous Route ${previousRoute}`)
}
```

Which log is:

```
_slug.js:200 before route called
_slug.js:202 Previous Route /
```

Comment: Yes, you have to use these hook in nuxt page component. Glad you solved!